# UL tags (from wysihtml5 javascript) doesnt align horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can i align these UL tags that has been manipulated by wysihtml5 text editor? Please help me. . . what css can i use to align them.

[image: how can i align these UL tags that has been manipulated by wysihtml5 text editor?]

Comment: Why don't you post a couple of lines of code you want to align?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class of `height-full` (*or whatever you want*) to the LI element and use the CSS:

```
.height-full {
    height: 100%;
}
```